# Array#product RangeError: too big to product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I have 93 arrays. Each array has about 18 values in average
I need to make a product of these arrays.

So I have my two dimension array that store these 93 arrays.

Here is what I try to do

```
DATASET.first.product(*DATASET[1..-1])
```

Ruby returns

```
RangeError: too big to product
```

Does anyone know some workaround to figure out of it?
Some ways to chunk them?

Comment: Ok, so such a product would consist of 18^93 subarrays. That's a massive amount! Why would you need such a monstrosity?

Comment: @BroiSatse property testing. of course, I know it's massive, but I need to solve it

Comment: WHy do you need such a massive array for property testing? 00

Comment: "of course, I know it's massive" – It appears that you don't know it's massive. You would need several trillions of trillions of trillions of copies of our entire universe, just to have enough material to even build the RAM to store a tiny fraction of it in.

Comment: Thats not a massiv amount, thats a massive^massive amount of data. I'm guessing this is more like in the vicinity of amount of data produced by humans ever. No way to solve thsis.

Comment: @Max: Close. You are off by about 20 orders of magnitude. Which just shows: even if you take into account that you probably underestimate how massive this amount of data is, you still massively underestimate the amount of the data, heck you even massively underestimate just how massively you underestimate the amount of data.

Comment: This sounds like a xy Problem to me. Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve with the generated array?

Comment: @Max: Oops, I just did it myself. If you were to convert every particle in the universe into storage, then the amount of data you would have to store *in each particle* is 20 orders of magnitude of all information produced by humans, ever. So, it's actually 100 orders of magnitude.

Comment: I like that Ruby raises this error upfront instead of just running out of memory.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, Yeah just tried the "1 bit per atom" math myself. Really not good at estimating those kinds of numbers.....

Comment: @spickermann ah yes, the famous "Running out of universe" error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is impossible.

The product of 93 arrays with ~18 elements each is an array with approximately 549975033204266172374216967425209467080301768557741749051999338598022831065169332830885722071173603516904554174087168 elements, each of which is a 93-element array.

This means you need 549975033204266172374216967425209467080301768557741749051999338598022831065169332830885722071173603516904554174087168 * 93 * 64bit of memory to store it, which is roughly 409181424703974032246417423764355843507744515806959861294687507916928986312485983626178977220953161016576988305520852992 bytes. That is about 40 orders of magnitude more than the number of particles in the universe. In other words, even if you were to convert *the entire universe* into RAM, you would still need to find a way to store on the order of 827180612553027 *yobibyte* on each and every particle in the universe; that is about 6000000000000000000000000 times the information content of the World Wide Web and 10000000000000000000000 times the information content of the dark web.

> Does anyone know some workaround to figure out of it? Some ways to chunk them?

Even if you process them in chunks, that doesn't change the fact that you still need to process 51147678087996754030802177970544480438468064475869982661835938489616123289060747953272372152619145127072123538190106624 elements. Even if you were able to process one element per CPU instruction (which is unrealistic, you will probably need dozens if not hundreds of instructions), and even if each instruction only takes one clock cycle (which is unrealistic, on current mainstream CPUs, each instruction takes multiple clock cycles), and even if you had a terahertz CPU (which is unrealistic, the fastest current CPUs top out at 5 GHz), and even if your CPU had a million cores (which is unrealistic, even GPUs only have a couple of thousand *extremely simple* cores), and even if your motherboard had a million sockets (which is unrealistic, mainstream motherboards only have a maximum of 4 sockets, and even the biggest supercomputers only have 10 million cores in total), and even if you had a million of those computers in a cluster, and even if you had a million of those clusters in a supercluster, and even if you had a million friends that also have a supercluster like this, it would *still* take you about 1621000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 years to iterate through them.

Comment: Word of warning - do not cite this answer to management, they'll only understand that it requires more RAM and will give you a deadline.

Comment: There are surely some physics arguments to be made why even attempting this would make the universe collapse in on itself, but I am pretty shaky with the science, unfortunately. There are theoretical limits on the energy required to store a bit, for example.

Comment: "Sounds good, when can this be done?"

Comment: great explanation! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Right, so as it is hopefully clear that this should not be attempted I'll take a risk and attempt solving your actual problem.

You've mentioned in the comments that you need this array for property testing - I'll take a massive leap of faith here and assume you want to test that every possible combination satisfies some conditions - and this is the mistake here, as the amount of possible combination is just... large...

Instead, you can test that some of the combinations works. You can easily generate a short, randomized list of combinations using:

```
Array.new(num) { DATASET.map(&:sample) }
```

Where `num` is a number of combinations you want to test. Note that there is a chance that some of the entries will be duplicated - but given your dataset size the chances would be comparable with colliding uuids and can be safely ignored.

Generating such a subset of possible solutions is much easier, faster and, most importantly, possible. Since the output is randomized, it will test slightly different combination on each run, so remember to have some randomization setup in your test suite if you want to be able to recreate failures.